# File names with spaces in scripts

Tags: bash, scripts

Here is a simple script to pass a file path to `ls` or `chmod` but filenames with spaces don't work even when enclosed in quote marks.

How do I get it to work ?

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Script to fix permissions on supplied folder and file name

echo "Enter Folder name"
read folder
echo "Folder name is "$folder
echo "Enter File name - if name includes spaces enclose in single quote marks"
read filename 

echo "File name is "$filename
fullpath="/home/abc/"$folder"/"$filename

echo "Full path is "$fullpath

fixcommand="chmod a+rw -v "$fullpath

echo "Command to be executed is "$fixcommand

echo -n "Is that correct (y/n)? "
read answer
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
$fixcommand
else
    echo No action taken
fi
```

Comment: Do not ask the user to quote the input string -- if the user enters quotes, they are just literal characters that must appear in the actual file name. Handle it in your code as Yaron answers.

Answer (score 8):

In the script provided by you, **the variables actually aren't quoted**.

You should update your script and quote the variables with " "

For example:

```
fullpath="/home/abc/"$folder"/"$filename
```

**Should be:**

```
fullpath="/home/abc/$folder/$filename"
```

> Thanks for @glenn jackman - who suggested reading [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

You can find below the full feedback of [shell-check site](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on your script

```
Line 5:
read folder
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 6:
echo "Folder name is "$folder
                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 8:
read filename
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 10:
echo "File name is "$filename
                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 11:
fullpath="/home/abc/"$folder"/"$filename
                     ^-- SC2027: The surrounding quotes actually unquote this. Remove or escape them.

Line 13:
echo "Full path is "$fullpath
                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 17:
echo "Command to be executed is "$fixcommand
                                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 19:
echo -n "Is that correct (y/n)? "
     ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, echo flags are undefined.

Line 20:
read answer
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
```

Comment: See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for the link. I've added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes don't mean anything to `read`, and will show up in the variable. Quotes inside a variable are also just regular characters: there's no step in the shell processing where quotes would take effect after a variable was expanded.

The only exception is if you explicitly add another layer of shell processing, either by running something like `bash -c "$somevar"`, or using `eval`. That's not a very good idea though, since usually you'd want to *avoid* mixing data and code.

---

So, what you need to do is to 1) have `read` pass the user's input to the variable with as few changes as possible, and then 2) use the variable within quotes to pass it from the shell to the command without changes.

`read filename` by itself is pretty much ok, it handles whitespace in the middle of the string. But it does strip leading and tailing whitespace and it treats backslashes as special characters. To turn those features off, use `IFS= read -r filename`.

When using the variable, you must run the command as  `chmod a+rw -v "$filename"`.

You can't save the whole thing to a variable, it will not be possible to split it back properly. `"$fixcommand"` will treat the whole value as a single string, the name of the command. `$fixcommand` will split your filename, too. ([BashFAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discusses saving a command to a variable)

---

All in all:

```
IFS= read -r filename 
fullpath="/home/abc/$folder/$filename"
echo "Command to be executed is: chmod a+rw -v \"$filename\""
# confirmation...
chmod a+rw -v "$filename"
```

Comment: IFS= read -r filename 
fullpath="/home/abc/$folder/$filename"
echo "Command to be executed is: chmod a+rw -v \"$filename\""
# confirmation...
chmod a+rw -v "$filename"

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all  Final working version is :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to fix permissions on supplied folder and file name                  
# including folders and filenames containing spaces
echo "Fixfilepermissions running" 

echo "Enter Folder name"
IFS= read -r folder
echo "Folder name is "$folder
echo "Enter File name"
IFS= read -r filename 
echo "File name is "$filename

fullpath="/home/abc/$folder/$filename"

echo "Full path is "$fullpath

echo "Command to be executed is: chmod a+rw -v \"$fullpath\""
echo -n "Is that correct (y/n)? "
read answer
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
chmod a+rw -v "$fullpath"
else
    echo "No action taken"
fi
```

Comment: But you only quoted some of them...